# Acumatica custom field needs PXSelector for specific attribute Description values

Tags: acumatica

I have added a custom field to a screen and want to have a Selector to choose values from the Description of a specific attribute called BASEITEM.

```
[PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Document Number", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<CSAttributeDetail.Description,
 Where<CSAttributeDetail.AttributeID.StartsWith("BASEITEM")>,
 OrderBy<Asc<CSAttributeDetail.Description>>>),
 DescriptionField = typeof(CSAttributeDetail.Description)]
```

However, when I try to publish this I get errors.

```
Building directory '/WebSiteValidationDomain/App_RuntimeCode/'.
/AcuDocCenterWebsite/App_RuntimeCode/PX_Objects_IN_InventoryItem_extensions.cs(27): error CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected
/AcuDocCenterWebsite/App_RuntimeCode/PX_Objects_IN_InventoryItem_extensions.cs(27): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ','
/AcuDocCenterWebsite/App_RuntimeCode/PX_Objects_IN_InventoryItem_extensions.cs(27): error CS1026: ) expected
/AcuDocCenterWebsite/App_RuntimeCode/PX_Objects_IN_InventoryItem_extensions.cs(27): error CS1003: Syntax error, ']' expected
/AcuDocCenterWebsite/App_RuntimeCode/PX_Objects_IN_InventoryItem_extensions.cs(28): error CS1519: Invalid token '>' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
/AcuDocCenterWebsite/App_RuntimeCode/PX_Objects_IN_InventoryItem_extensions.cs(29): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
/AcuDocCenterWebsite/App_RuntimeCode/PX_Objects_IN_InventoryItem_extensions.cs(29): error CS1519: Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Compiler time, seconds: 0.8243028
Validation failed.
```

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, you are missing a parenthesis at the end. `DescriptionField = typeof(CSAttributeDetail.Description))]`

Comment: I added the parenthesis you recommended...still error

Comment: [PXDBString(60, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Document Number", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<CSAttributeDetail.Description),
 Where<CSAttributeDetail.AttributeID.StartsWith("BASEITEM")>,
 OrderBy<Asc<CSAttributeDetail.Description>>>),
 DescriptionField = typeof(CSAttributeDetail.Description))]

Comment: error CS1003: Syntax error, '>' expected
error CS1525: Invalid expression term ','
 error CS1026: ) expected
/AcuDocCenterWebsite/App_RuntimeCode/PX_Objects_IN_InventoryItem_extensions.cs(27): error CS1003: Syntax error, ']' expected
error CS1519: Invalid token '>' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
error CS1519: Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of strange things in your attributes, so let's try if fixing them will resolve your problem. Here is the complete snippet that should work :

```cs
    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Document Number", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<CSAttributeDetail.description,
     Where<CSAttributeDetail.attributeID,  Like<string_BASEITEMPCT>>,
     OrderBy<Asc<CSAttributeDetail.description>>>),
     DescriptionField = typeof(CSAttributeDetail.description))]
```

Here is the constant class used in the `PXSelector` attribute

```cs
    public class string_BASEITEMPCT : Constant<string>
    {
        public string_BASEITEMPCT()
            : base("BASEITEM%")
        {
        }
    }
```

1. You were missing a parenthesis at the end of the `PXSelector` attribute which prevented build and publish.
2. You need to use the classes inheriting `IBqlField` instead of specific field  i.e. use the lowercase class instead of the uppercase field when doing BQL.
3. To compare a field value to a string, use the `Like<>` operator and a string constant. To create that constant, create a class and specify the string value as the argument of the base constructor. The `%` at the end of `"BASEITEM%"` has the same purpose as the SQL wildcard `%`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Simon!  One more question...where do I define the constant class for the string_BASEITEMPCT ?

Comment: It is pretty much up to you, as long as the class is accessible by the attribute. A good pratice would be the aggregate all constant in a single file, Constants.cs